# Accessing Backbone.JS colection.fetch POST payload using Node.JS express framework

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I'm sending POST request to the server from Backbone.JS using the following code

```
Courses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                url:'/courses'
            });
var courses = new Courses();
courses.fetch({data:{course_name:"data structures"},type:'POST' });
```

At the backend i'm using Node.JS Express framework and listening  to the request using

```
app.post('/courses',function(req,res){
   console.log('POST reached');
});
```

but i'm not the able access the POST data or POST payload sent from Backbone.JS fetch method .
I tried **req.body.data , req.body.course_name , req.body.data.course_name** , they are not giving me the POST data . How to obtain the POST payload ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var CourseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var CourseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: CourseModel
  url: '/courses'
});
var courses = new CourseCollection();
courses.create({course_name:"data structures"});
```

Then in your Express route, you should see it come through in the req.body.

```
app.post('/courses',function(req, res){
   console.log('POST: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

Also, you need to make sure you include the proper middleware to handle the JSON data in the body. Example:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

For more recent versions of Express, use this instead:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Comment: The POST request is being sent , but getting POST:undefined at the backend.Here is the code from my GITHUB repo https://github.com/Karthic-Hackintosh/Codes-From-My-Blog-posts/tree/master/112

Comment: From looking at the code snippet, it looks like you are missing some middleware. I updated my answer.